# Passing an object to attributes of directive in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a directive which creates a modal.I am trying to pass an object through attributes to this directive.

```
 <modal-dialog model="viewSummaryDialog" info="{{info}}"></modal-dialog>
```

And I'm retrieving it through attributes like this

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    model: '=',
    info:'@',
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
   scope.info=scope.$eval(attributes.info);
```

In my HTML info is an object which has ng-model of different text fields and dropdowns
My problem is that info is not being updated with whatever I enter in the text fields.I am getting only auto selected drop down values in my info object in the directive.I understand this is because link function is being called even before I enter anything in text fields.
Is there any way to make sure that my info object is passed only after I enter all the fields in the form? I am not very clear about how to pass an object to the directive.I tried using resolve function also in my directive but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: maybe if you provide relevant parts of code we could help

Answer (score 0):

Passing object to directive

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { object: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{object.prop}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.object = { prop: "world" };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object object="object"></pass-object>
</div>
```